# What is $\lim_{x→1^{-}} (1 – x^2)^{\frac{1}{\log(1 – x)}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

The question was from a set of questions for mathematics pg entrance examination.
$$\lim_{x→1^{-}} (1 – x^2)^{\dfrac{1}{\log(1 – x)}}$$

> The correct answer that was given was $e$

$\log L=\lim_{x→1^{-}}\dfrac{\log(1 – x^2)}{\log(1 – x)}$

I am stuck here, since $\log 0$ is undefined, I believe I cannot use L Hopital's rule.How can I solve this question?

Comment: Note that $1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$

Comment: ... and that $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$ ($\forall a,b\in\Bbb R_+$). And that $\log0$ is not really "undefined": more precisely, $\log(0^+)=-\infty.$ And if $c\ne0$, neither is $\frac c{\infty}$ undefined: it is $0.$

Comment: $\ln0$ doesn't have to be defined for L'Hôpital's rule to be applicable, as long as it has a limit (in this case $-\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{\ln(1-x)}=\frac{\ln[(1-x)(1+x)]}{\ln(1-x)}=\frac{\ln(1-x)+\ln(1+x)}{\ln(1-x)}=1+\underbrace{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln(1-x)}}_{\to0}\to1$$

as $x\to1^-$, and so, as this is the logarithm of the limit, it follows by continuity that the limit equals $e^1=e$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I disagree on OP not showing any effort. OP still took the logarithm of the limit and tried to work with that, and pointed out exactly where they got stuck, i.e. they wanted to apply L'Hôpital's rule but was unsure about whether that was allowed.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. +1. But may be my incomplete comment would have been more pedagogical, to let neo work a little more and find the answer by himself.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Lorago, "$\ln0$ doesn't have to be defined for L'Hôpital's rule to be applicable, as long as it has a limit (in this case $−∞$)".

More precisely, by the [second case of L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form), as $x\to1^-,$
$$\frac{(\ln(1-x^2))'}{(\ln(1-x))'}=\frac{\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}}{\frac{-1}{1-x}}=\frac{2x}{1+x}\to1,$$
hence $\ln L=1$ and $L=e^1=e.$